# Problem with Expected Value (with conditional!)

Tags: probability

this is my first post on Maths so sorry if I haven't done this properly! I've been told that **y = A + BX + C**, and that **E(C|X) = 0**.

They've then jumped to the conclusion that **E(y|X) = A + BX**.

So I get that E(C|X) = 0, and C = y - (A + BX), so E(y-(A + BX)|X) = 0.

Just not sure how they've just moved the (A + BX) to the other side to get E(y|X) = A + BX, can you just move it to the other side or am I being an idiot?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just move it to the right side. You'll have to move it with the conditional expectation (linearity of expectation). In other words, $\mathbb{E}[H - G\,|\,K] \iff \mathbb{E}[H\,|\,K] = \mathbb{E}[G\,|\,K]$.

So what you have to do is convince yourself that $\mathbb{E}[(A + BX)\,|\,X] = A + BX$. If $A$ and $B$ are constants, then it reduces to understanding that $\mathbb{E}[X|X] = X$, which should be easy.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: You are welcome. I suspect you see this for linear regression or something? Where the C is a centered Gaussian noise?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that A is deterministic we have that $\mathbb{E}(A|X)=A$. Assuming furthermore that $X$ is stochastic we can use that $\mathbb{E}(BX|X)$ is simply $BX$.